# Filling up a new column with values based on 2 window dates in another dataframe (in Pandas and PySpark)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I have 2 dataframes. df1 looks like this:

```
DATE    QUANTITY
2015-10-28  14
2015-10-29  881 
2015-10-30  533
2015-10-31  634
2015-11-01  637
```

...

I have a second df, df2 which is like this:

```
STARTDATE      ENDDATE     VALUE
2015-10-25     2015-10-29   2 
2015-11-01     2015-11-15   3
```

The second df defines a window... and I would like to fill up the
first df with this window information like this...

Final df

```
DATE    QUANTITY    VALUE
2015-10-25  nan     2
2015-10-26  nan     2
2015-10-27  nan     2
2015-10-28  14      2
2015-10-29  881     2
2015-10-30  533     0
2015-10-31  634     0
2015-11-01  637     3
2015-11-02  nan     3
2015-11-03  nan     3
2015-11-04  nan     3
...
2015-11-15  nan     3
```

How do I do this in pandas and how do I do this in PySpark ?

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pandas**:

You can create a date range using `pd.to_datetime` and then explode followed by an outer merge:

Starting with converting the date values to datetime dtype (ignore this step if already a datetime dtype)

```
df2[['STARTDATE','ENDDATE']] = df2[['STARTDATE','ENDDATE']].apply(pd.to_datetime)
df1['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['DATE'])
```

---

```
e = df2[['VALUE']].join(df2.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['STARTDATE'],x['ENDDATE']),axis=1)
                        .explode().rename("DATE"))
final = e.merge(df1,on='DATE',how='outer')[['DATE','VALUE','QUANTITY']] #ordering is optional
print(final.sort_values("DATE"))

        DATE  VALUE  QUANTITY
0  2015-10-25    2.0       NaN
1  2015-10-26    2.0       NaN
2  2015-10-27    2.0       NaN
3  2015-10-28    2.0      14.0
4  2015-10-29    2.0     881.0
20 2015-10-30    NaN     533.0
21 2015-10-31    NaN     634.0
5  2015-11-01    3.0     637.0
6  2015-11-02    3.0       NaN
.........
.......
```

---

**PySpark**

I am assuming the datetime types are already applied, if not convert the date columns using `to_date`:

Using `sequence` to generate the date series and then explode followed by an outer join:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
final = (sdf2.select(F.explode(F.sequence("STARTDATE","ENDDATE")).alias("DATE"),"VALUE")
        .join(sdf1,on='DATE',how='outer').fillna({"VALUE":0}))
final.show()

+----------+-----+--------+
|      DATE|VALUE|QUANTITY|
+----------+-----+--------+
|2015-10-25|    2|    null|
|2015-10-26|    2|    null|
|2015-10-27|    2|    null|
|2015-10-28|    2|      14|
|2015-10-29|    2|     881|
|2015-10-30|    0|     533|
|2015-10-31|    0|     634|
|2015-11-01|    3|     637|
|2015-11-02|    3|    null|
.......
......
```

Comment: Thank you - I was looking for this concise version of a solution.

Comment: @Sdn Glad it helped you . The `.fillna({"VALUE":0})` is applicable for both solutions, I had missed adding it on the pandas solution

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example for you. It's self explanatory so you will understand.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Creating a sample dataset
date = np.array('2015-10-28', dtype=np.datetime64)
date = date + np.arange(5)
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Date'] = date
df1['Quantity'] = [10,20,30,40,50]
display(df1)
date1 = pd.period_range('2015-10-25', periods=5, freq='3D')
date2 = pd.period_range('2015-10-30', periods=5, freq='3D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['StartDate'] = date1
df2['EndDate'] = date2
df2['value'] = [2,2,2,2,2]
display(df2)

# Solving the problem
date_range = []
values = []
for i,j, value in df2[['StartDate', 'EndDate', 'value']].values:
    dates = np.arange(str(i), str(j), dtype=np.datetime64)
    date_range += list(dates)
    values += [value]*len(dates)

temp_df = pd.DataFrame()
temp_df['Date'] = date_range
temp_df['Value'] = values

final_df = df1.merge(temp_df, on='Date', how='outer')
display(final_df)
```

If it solved your problem then kindly the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it, this problem needs a range join, which is not possible to do natively in pandas (AFAIK). The below combination of pandas as SQLite should solve the problem without needing a cross-join (which would blow up the number of rows) or loops.

```
# solution using pandas as sqlite
#### Setup
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
lst1 = [
['2015-10-28' ,14],
['2015-10-29' ,881],
['2015-10-30' ,533],
['2015-10-31' ,634],
['2015-11-01' ,637]
]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(lst1, columns = ['DATE','QUANTITY'])

lst2 = [
    ['2015-10-25','2015-10-29',2],
    ['2015-11-01','2015-11-15',3]
]

df2= pd.DataFrame(lst2, columns = ['STARTDATE','ENDDATE','VALUE'])

#### Solution

# Create dataframe with all required dates between STARTDATE and ENDDATE in df_2
dt_df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start = df2['STARTDATE'].min(), end=df2['ENDDATE'].max()),columns = ['DATE'])
dt_df['DATE'] = dt_df['DATE'].astype('str')

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:") 
df1.to_sql("df1", conn, index=False)
df2.to_sql("df2", conn, index=False)
dt_df.to_sql("dt_df", conn, index=False)
sql = """
select 
     dt_df.DATE
    ,df1.QUANTITY
    ,df2.VALUE
from
    dt_df
left join
    df1
on
    dt_df.DATE = df1.DATE
left join
    df2
on
    dt_df.DATE >= df2.STARTDATE
and
    dt_df.DATE <= df2.ENDDATE
"""
op_df = pd.read_sql_query(sql,conn)
op_df
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!  I would have liked to avoid SQLite as much as possible.